# Logic of Calling a Variable of a class from another class

Tags: php, oop, logic

I have a few questions:
so, I have a class A as follows:

```
class A {   
protected $ _blah = 'blah';   

public __construct {
$this-> setPath ('test');
new B;
}

public setPath ($ path) {
$ This -> _ blah = $ path;
}
}
```

I have a Class B as follows:

```
class B extends A {
`echo $ this -> _ blah`;
}
```

nah, why is the output: 'blah' and not 'test' in class B.
however, I have changed the variable in class A to 'test' before my instance of class B.

Comment: Don't put a space after `$`. It works, but it's not common style and makes your code harder for everyone else to read.

Comment: The spaces around `->` are also not common style.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have backticks around the `echo` statement?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, the problem is likely because you are calling `$This` instead of `$this`.

For reference, have a look at how PHP handles [object inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php). Because variables are case sensitive, you are not actually changing the property of your class in the posted code.

A better example would be the following:

```
class A
{
    public $property = 'foo';
}

class B extends A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->property = 'baz';
    }
}

// 'foo';
echo A::$property;

$b = new B;

// 'baz'
echo $b->property;
```